# Time difference in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function in SQL Server which returns difference in time:

```
create function [dbo].[GetTimeDiffrence] (@dutyHour time, @ShiftTime time)
returns time(0)
as 
begin
     declare @result time(0);
     declare @null time;

     set @null = '00:00:00';

     select
         @result = case
                      when DATEDIFF(SECOND, @dutyHour, @ShiftTime) <= 0
                        then DATEADD(SECOND, -DATEDIFF(SECOND, @dutyHour, @ShiftTime), @null)
                      when DATEDIFF(SECOND, @dutyHour, @ShiftTime) > 0
                        then DATEADD(SECOND,  DATEDIFF(SECOND, @dutyHour, @ShiftTime), @null)
                   end

     return @result;
end
GO
```

It works, `SELECT [dbo].[GetTimeDiffrence_test] ('08:00:00','08:30:00')` returns an output of `00:30:00`.

But if I change the statement to

```
SELECT [dbo].[GetTimeDiffrence_test] ('48:00:00','48:30:00')
```

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Also, how can I get difference in minus as well?

Comment: Use INTERVAL data type instead of TIME?

Comment: @jarlh Is there such a datatype in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your `time` parameters. Variables declared as time, range from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. Take a look at [**the docs**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx).

Sending values which are "greater" than 24 hours will not work.

Comment: what is the best way to store 48 hrs 30 min in db.

Comment: @Vikky Do you actually want to store this? Or are you actually trying to get difference between two dates?

Comment: i have a scenario, actually it is overtime for employees, if the duty time is 08:00:00 and he worked only 07:30:00 , i have to show -00:30:00 and on monthly report i have to deduct this half an hour from the total overtime

Comment: @Vikky Do you run this function on a table? I have a feeling you can solve your problem with a simple aggregate. Do you have a table with `employee_id`, `time_worked_per_day`, `day` or something like this?